Convergence of Trailing and Leading Maxima of an IID Sequence of Random Variables
I am reading a research paper and have come across a step in a proof that essentially reduces to the following problem: Let $X_1, ..., X_n$ be a sequence of IID continuous, positive random variables with CDF $F_x(x)$ and density $f_x(x)$. Define $M_1 = \max \{X_1, X_2, ..., X_{n - \delta(n)}\}$ and $M_2 = \max \{X_1, X_2, ..., X_{n + \delta(n)} \}$ as the trailing and leading maximums respectively. Here, $\delta(n) = O(n^{1/2})$. How can we show that
$$\lim_{n \longrightarrow \infty} P(M_1 = M_2) = 1.$$
Here's what I've come up with. First, since $M_1, M_2$ are formed on the same sequence, it follows that $M_1 \le M_2$ since any maximum "seen" by $M_1$ is necessarily also seen by $M_2$. Hence, to demonstrate the property we need to demonstrate
$$\lim_{n \longrightarrow \infty} P(M_2 \le M_1) = 1.$$
We can condition on $M_1$ and use the definition of a maximum to see that:
\begin{align*}
 P(M_2 \le M_1) &= \int_{m_1 = 0}^\infty P(M_2 \le m_1) P(M_1 = m_1) \: d m_1 \\
&= \int_{m_1 = 0}^\infty F_x(m_1)^{2\delta(n)} \frac{d}{dm_1}\left[ F_x(m_1)^{n - \delta} \right]\: dm_1.
\end{align*}
Adding the limits, we have
$$\lim_{n \longrightarrow \infty} \lim_{m \longrightarrow \infty} \int_0^m F_x(x)^{2\delta(n)} \frac{d}{dx}\left[F_x(x)^{n - \delta} \right] \: dx. $$
However, I cannot find out how to show this limit goes to $1$. Any thoughts or resources here would be appreciated. I also wonder if there is a more "clever" way to show this using the exchangeability of the random variables, or perhaps stronger conditions needed for the limit. Thanks.

Since the $X_i$ are continuous, the random variables $X_1,\ldots,X_{n+\delta(n)}$ are almost-surely distinct, and hence have a unique maximum. Since they are also iid, $\mathbb{P}(X_i = M_2) = \frac{1}{n+\delta(n)}$ for each $i$. Putting this together we have $$\mathbb{P}(M_1 = M_2) = \mathbb{P}(X_i = M_2 \text{ for some } i\in \{1,\ldots,n-\delta(n)\}) = \frac{n-\delta(n)}{n+\delta(n)} \xrightarrow{n\to \infty} 1.$$

Hello @raj why is the second equality valid? I can see $\leq$.

@snoop could be wrong but expand the OR and notice that the intersections are 0 due to almost-surely distinct property and independence?

@snoop hmmmm. My understanding is that raj is finding the probability that the value realized by $M_2$ occurs in the trailing part of the sequence, ${X_1, ..., X_{n - \delta(n)} }$. However, do you think that some implicit conditioning on $M_2$ is being done here?

Yes as @Alek_ says, if you let $A$ be the event the $X_i$ are all distinct, the LHS is also equal to $\mathbb{P}(A, X_i = M_2\text{ for some }i \in {1,\ldots,n-\delta(n)})$ since $\mathbb{P}(A) = 1$. Furthermore this probability is the same as the probability of $\bigcup_{i \in {1,\ldots,n-\delta(n)}} (A\cap {X_i=M_2})$ which is a disjoint union, so we get the RHS (again using $\mathbb{P}(A) = 1$ as well as $\mathbb{P}(X_i = M_2) = 1/(n+\delta(n)$).
